# Print content from a list with a delay in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of strings in Javascript that I would like to print into a HTML div. This is the Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
list = ["One","Two","Three"];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    $("#content").html(list[i]);
}
});
```

Which print into the HTML div with the id "content". But of course only the last word shows up. What I would like is control the delay between each $("#content").html(list[i]); so I can see every word of the list one after each other. Is there a solution in Javascript or jQuery ?

Thanks !

Comment: are you wanting to overwrite the previous content? Or are you just wanting to see each word being replaced and the final outcome is, the last word in the array?

Comment: got it... its a countdown isn't it...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gVtbZ/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 list = ["One","Two","Three"];
 index = 0;
 intr = setInterval(yourfun, 2000);

 function yourfun()
 { 
    $("#content").html(list[index++]);
    if(index == 3) clearInterval(intr);
 }
});
```

You can use `append` to add content in previous, check it [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/gVtbZ/1/).

Answer (score 1):

First of all , you can use `$.each()` call instead of `for` statement

```
$.each(list , function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   $("#content").text(this)  
 , 1000)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using a promise generating function:

```
var list = ["One","Two","Three"];
var waitingTime = 1000;
function promiseToChangeText(i){
    return function (){
              $("#content").text(list[i])
           }
}
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    setTimeout(promiseToChangeText(i),
               waitingTime*(i+1));
}
```

using each:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = ["One","Two","Three"];
    var waitingTime = 1000;
    $(list).each( function (i,listItem) {
        setTimeout(function (){$("#content").
                                   text(listItem.toString())},
                   waitingTime*(i+1));
    });
});
```